# Message about font in an existent fla

Tags: flash, fonts

I receive a FLA and when I try to run in Flash CS6 I can see this message:

> Fonts should be embedded for any text that may be edited at runtime, other than text with the "Use Device Fonts" setting. Use the Text > Font Embedding command to embed fonts.

This FLA uses 2 fonts that I don't have in my macbook, but I believe the flash try to mapping to some existent font in my system (at least, when I open the FLA the flash show one pop-up with this option).

My question is... what is going on? How I can fix it?

Comment: @Oswald - that is not an appropriate use of the `embedded` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **What's going on?**

The fonts were present in the system when the fla was created. Now flash finds the fonts missing & hence shows an alternative to you at the starting.

After selecting the alternative, the swf produced, also relies on the system where it would be run, to have the fonts installed.

> **How can I fix it?**

To fix the first error (choosing of alternative) you would have to install the font. Try googling for the font name. If it's a commercial font, you might have to purchase it.

Now if you need make sure the font selected during compilation to be available in user's system, you would have to embed the font.

For this, Go to :   `Text -> Fonts Embedding -> Select the font and add required symbols`

Only downside to this is that it increases the swf size.

If it's a very common font (like Arial) you might just set all the dynamic text boxes to *"Use Device Fonts"* which would remove the font errors altogether. Say currently, you might have selected *"anti-alias for animation"* for the dynamic text boxes in your fla.

Answer (score 0):

one more solution ( an addition to @loxxy answer )

When flash shows you the font missing window, note down the font which is missing then:

Go to : Text -> Fonts Embedding -> Select the font and remove the font you note down before.

Also add alternate font as required.

Now flash will not prompt you any more.